# Binding value to tableviewcell in Xamarin iOS programatically

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, tableview

I am new to Xamarin mobile application Development.

Added new file into project `iOS Table View Controller`, it created three .cs files into my project.

```
  1) CustomTableviewCell.cs
  2) CustomTableviewController.cs
  3) CustomTableViewSource.cs
```

In MainViewController.cs which is UIViewController Class have parsed data

```
 {
      "data": [
        {
          “Metr0”: {
            "id": "1",
            “companyName”: “demo Industry2”,
          }
        },
        {
          “Metro: {
            "id": “2”,
            “companyName”: "demo Industry",
         }
        },
     ]
    }
```

I created CustomTableviewController.cs Object in inside MainViewController.cs

```
    public MainViewController(){
     tableviewObject = new  CustomTableviewController ();
     tableviewObject.Frame = View.Frame;
    }

   View.AddSubView(tableviewObject);
```

Customize CustomTableviewCell

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace IOS
{
    public class CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        UILabel headingLabel1;
        UILabel headingLabel2;
        UILabel headingLabel3;
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("CustomTableViewCell");
        public CustomTableViewCell () : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, Key){

            headingLabel1 = new UILabel () {
                Text = "value",
                Frame = new RectangleF(20, 10, ContentView.Bounds.Width - 63, 12),
                Font = UIFont.FromName("Cochin", 12f),
                TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB (127, 51, 0),
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
            };

            ContentView.Add (headingLabel1);
```

Can any one advice me for binding the `companyName` into CustomTableViewCell by sending data from UIviewcontroller to uitableviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You create the cell and populate it with data in the UITableViewSource class.  In your controller, instantiate your Source class and assign it to the TableView's Source property.  You will probably want to pass the underlying data source (ie, your JSON data) to the Source class.

In the Source class, there are three methods (at a minimum) that you need to override.

```
// how many rows are in each section
public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)

// how many sections are there?
public override int NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)

// for each row, build the cell, and assign it's data
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
```

Xamarin has fairly [extensive docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/) on working with TableViews.